# Use methods of DLLs into other ones

Tags: c++, dll, export, executable

I have 3 DLLS and one win32 project in the same solution. The win32 project should use methods and classes of the DLLs and the DLLs should use methods of the other ones.

How can I do this? Should I include the .h files of every DLLs in the other ones?

Also, I have a function in one DLL that initialize a class defined in the header file of the DLL, how can I call it in the win32 project so that it creates the instance but valid also for the others DLLs?

Comment: Could you explain the rationale behind the spreading of this code across these DLLs. They all sound very interlinked, so why are they separated?

Comment: If i separate the DLLs I have one for a specific thing like a network dll and one for another specific thing like a 3d engine

Comment: And do you need them to be able to operate independent of each other? Do you ever deploy them on their own? By the way, please put @somebody's_name in your comment so that they get notified. Otherwise you are just talking to yourself.

Comment: @David: Congratulations on reaching 10k rep!

Comment: @Andreas Thank you! When did trusted user get added to the available privileges? I thought once you got to 10k there was nothing else to chase!!

Comment: @David: sorry, didn't know about the name thing :D anyway I must have these dlls separated, so how could I fix my problem?

Comment: you just link to a DLL with .h and .lib files

Comment: @David: Very recently. I was quite surprised when I saw that (yesterday), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what your problem is. You link to DLLs using header and lib files. I think you already know this.

If you want to share an instance between code in different DLLs you need to export that instance just like you export the classes and functions. You can export the symbol directly, or provide a function to obtain a reference to the instance.

You seem to be saying that DLL A refers to DLL B and vice versa. In which case, despite your protestations to the contrary in the comments, it would be easier to combine them into one DLL.

Comment: @David yes this is another problem, i have an instance initialized in the win32 project that i would share beetween dlls

Comment: Get those DLLs to export a function that is passed a reference to that instance. When the main exe starts, call that function in each of those DLLs. That function then remembers the reference, and they are all referring to the same instance. Job done.

Comment: @Stefano What don't you understand about what I said in my last comment? You communicate between two modules (exe to dll say) with a function call that passes the shared reference across the boundary. Why should I spend my time writing code samples for you? You can't even give out an up-vote!!

Comment: @David I don't give an up vote simply because the reply is incomplete, you limited your words in saying that I should create e function... If I asked in my question how could I do it I would expect a simple code of example, not an offensive comment. And I also remember you that this is a public place, if you are not interested in help users don't help them

Comment: @Stefano I don't think you should expect anything! You should just be grateful that people give up their time to help you. It so happens that I like doing this but it almost sounds as though you are taking it for granted. Anyway, since you have created apps and DLLs and since you appear to know about linking, .lib files etc., I didn't think you'd need a code sample. Did you write all this code yourself, or are you working with architecture designed by someone else?

Comment: @Stefano And the reply is not incomplete. It doesn't need a code sample to make it complete. The nature of your question and the comments made me suspect that you are a proficient programmer. I thought a code sample of a function with a single parameter containing a reference to an object instance would have been condescending for someone of your coding skills. That's why I haven't done it!

Comment: I know how to do the function but I don't understand how should I implement it to make it available in the other DLLs. What I mean is: should i export it with __declspec(export) and call it normally?

Comment: @Stefano It's `__declspec(dllexport)`, or `__declspec(dllimport)` on the other side, the same as the other things that you export, I presume. Call it as soon as this object is created, you can't call it sooner, and once you've created the object there's no point delaying.

Comment: @Stefano Is this helpful to you?

Comment: @Stefano Great. Glad we got over my abruptness and rudeness! Sorry.